# MSAL Android Xamarin Stuck Dialog - "Are you trying to sign in to {your_appname}"?

Tags: android, azure, azure-ad-msal

We are using MSAL through Azure Portal in single tenant mode.
App is Xamarin forms, platform Android, debugging in simulator or on Samsung phone have same results.

This dialog comes up and pressing the buttons gives nothing.
Pressing "continue" does nothing and no output comes to the debugger
Pressing "cancel" does nothing and no output comes to the debugger

The app is authenticating, we can see it in the Azure Portal logs every time we click "continue"
If we click "continue" 3 times, we see 3 confirmed authentications in the Azure Portal logs.

Why does this dialog not respond to the button clicks?

[image]

Comment: Azure portal is showing 1 error, and then success for each time we hit "continue"  The error is  50199
For security reasons, user confirmation is required for this request. Please repeat the request allowing user interaction

Comment: Error explanation can be found here    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes    AADSTS50199 CmsiInterrupt - For security reasons, user confirmation is required for this request. Because this is an "interaction_required" error, the client should do interactive auth. This occurs because a system webview has been used to request a token for a native application - the user must be prompted to ask if this was actually the app they meant to sign into.

Comment: To avoid this prompt, the redirect URI should be part of the following safe list:
http://
https://
msauth://(iOS only)
msauthv2://(iOS only)
chrome-extension:// (desktop Chrome browser only)              

The problem is that azure portal will not let us change the reply URL, the part with msauth://   is hardwired by azure when setting up the app registration and login scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was fixed by adding this
.WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)

Now the dialog no longer comes up

```
            result = await authContext.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes)
                .WithAuthority(Authority)
                .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
                .WithParentActivityOrWindow(pwindow)
                .ExecuteAsync();
```