# MSAL - react native for android stuck dialog : "Are you trying to sign in to ...."?

Tags: android, react-native, msal

I am a mobile developer (react native - android). I am using MSAL as login mechanism. I have been testing my application and I am stuck in the confirmation page of MSAL (this is the part when MSAL use the browser to interact with the user before allowing to enter the app or the page with "‌Are you trying to sign in to {your_appname}"‌?) when I click "‌Continue"‌ button it doesn't do anything, and there is no error message appeared, so I don'‌t have any clues about what is going on. This problem has never happened before.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDo4t.jpg)

I am trying to search all related issue, I found that it probably caused by AADSTS50199 CmsiInterrupt - For security reasons, user confirmation is required for this request. Because this is an "interaction_required" error, the client should do interactive auth.

I also found an article : [MSAL Android Xamarin Stuck Dialog - "Are you trying to sign in to {your_appname}"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69381228/msal-android-xamarin-stuck-dialog-are-you-trying-to-sign-in-to-your-appname/69453574#69453574)

but I think he is not using React native as programming language.

Is there a way to skip this confirmation page? or any solutions ?